# Using sed to replace a number located between two other numbers

Tags: sed

I need to replace a numeric value, that occurs in a specific line of a series of config files in a pattern like this:

string number_1 number_to_replace number_2

I want to obtain something like this:

string number_1 number_replaced number_2

The difficulties I encountered are:

- number_1 or number_2 can be equal to number_to_replace, so a simple replacement is not possible.
- number_1 and number_2 vary between config files so I don't know them in advance.

The closest attempt I got until now is:

```
echo "field 4 4 4" | sed 's/\s4\s/3/'
```

Which ouputs:

```
field34 4
```

This is close, given that I want to replace the intermediate number I added another "\s" to try to use the known fact that the line starts with a character.

```
echo "field 4 4 4" | sed 's/\s\s4\s/3/'
```

Which gives:

```
field 4 4 4
```

So, nothing is replaced this time. How can I proceed? A somewhat detailed explanation would be ideal, because my knowledge of replacing expressions that involve patterns in nearly zero.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below, which matches your exact sequence of digits as in the example. You could replace `3` with any digit of your choice.

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{1,\}\)[[:space:]]\([0-9]\{1,\}\)[[:space:]]\([0-9]\{1,\}\)/\1 3 \3/'
```

Notice that I've used the POSIX bracket expression to match the whitespace character which should be supported in any variant of `sed` you are using. Note that `\s` is supported in only the GNU variants.

The literal meaning of the regex definition is to match a single digit followed by a space, then a digit and space and another digit. The captured groups are stored from `\1`. Since your intention is to remove the 2<sup>nd</sup> digit, you replace that with the word of your choice.

If the extra escapes causes it unreadable, use the `-E` flag for extended regex support. I've used the default [BRE version](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03)